# Why is Flask giving me the same output?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to write a very first simple code using FLASK framework
 and to print hello world on the browser. The problem is every time I
 use sublime text 3 or pycharm it works and displays output only the
 first time and then when I make changes lets say *hello world* to *hello
 universe*, but all I get the old output. The only way I get the updated
 output if I restart my laptop or uninstall and install the software again.
 I tried chrome, safari, and IE. I also tried to clear the cache but I
 really don't know where the problem is

Comment: Try changing the port number

Comment: do i need to change the port in code or just in broswer?

Comment: Try changing both, and make sure to save your new code

Comment: ok so i change the port by this code app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6000) but its not accessing the page on this port and still working on port 5000

Comment: Did you stop the previous program with control-c?

Comment: i am using sublime text3 and there is only option i see to build the program but yeah in pycharm i see the option to sop the program and i stopped it made changes in code but i dont see any changes when i open the browser

Comment: And you saved the code too right?

Comment: yes offcourse i saved it .i just noticed that even when i run sublime text3 whose files i saved on desktop and pycharm files saved in pycharmproject folder. both are accessing same file whenever i open the browser means from PycharmProjects. but when i restart the pc then for the first time everything works perfect

Comment: Try saving the file in a different folder, and run it from Terminal/Command Prompt. Then we will know if it is a problem with the editor or the code

Comment: so i did a one more restart and its working in pycharm now but not in sublime.and now its working fine ...but i really dont know why i face this unexpected behavior lolz.anyway thanks for your time